# JSON.parse SyntaxError: Unexpected token ? in JSON at position 124

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax

I am trying to reload the list of options for  element dynamically, using $.ajax(). The response body consists of two fields: the dropdown HTML and the number of options, like so:
[image]

Then I simply insert the HTML into the  element:

```
success: function (response) {
                    $("#cmbComplianceUser").html(response.data);
}
```

When the list of options does not contain any special characters , it works OK. But when it does, for example:

```
<option value='845'>Amanda_~!@#$%^&*&#40;&#41;_+{}[]|?/:; Kildee_~!@#$%^&*&#40;&#41;_+{}[]|?/:;</option>
```

I get the following error:

[image]

What should I do to parse the html content correctly without any errors, and why wouldn't it parse the "?" symbol?

Comment: Ur JSON data got corrupted while serialization. Its not that JSON.parse() is not able to parse '?'.The problem is because this symbol is distorting the format of JSON.

Answer (score 0):

kind of figured out this one myself. i was trying to use JSON format without proper parsing the output string to JSON. Added toJSON() parse function on server:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/json"
Response.Write  "{ ""data"": " & toJSON(dropdownHtml) & ", ""total"": " & userCount & " }"
```